# What is the best way to make games in C# .NET?

Tags: c#, .net, windows, 2d

I have a little experience in making small time game applets in Java, and A LOT of experience in making games with Python/Pygame. I also know a like of SFML (C++) and SDL (C). I usually develop games in Pygame but its SLOW... performance is a constant nag. So I was looking for some good game library when I noticed the growing number of games developed in C#. I know a little of Windows Forms, and I know that It has a good Graphics API which wraps GDI. But which library is SERIOUSLY recommended? I know about SFML .NET and TAO SDL , should I use one of those? Or is Windows Forms alright? I was thinking of XNA but I have heard it needs a license and you need to BUY the XNA Game Studio. So which library should I use?

Comment: 2013 Update: XNA is dead. Therefore, the best options (IMO) is to use MonoGame or the SharpDX Toolkit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

XNA is free for PC development; it only costs money to develop for the Windows Phone and XBox (and use their marketplace) -- PC games are still free ([source](http://create.msdn.com/en-us/home/about/how_it_works)):

> The App Hub website is exclusively for Windows Phone and Xbox LIVE Indie Games developers.

It's an extremely good framework, and I'd suggest going through their tutorial, and then checking out some of the samples in their [education catalog](http://create.msdn.com/en-US/education/catalog/).

Comment: Is XNA also valid for COMMERCIAL PC Game development? Or can you only make free games?

Comment: Sure -- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magicka comes to mind. It had a rocky release, but I personally blame the team rather than the framework for that.

Comment: One note I missed: if you use the MS Live (and related networking) in XNA, you also need to become a member: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_XNA#License_Agreement

Comment: Nah, personally im not that good at networking. Single Player games are enough for me.

Answer (score 1):

Nope!
XNA is free :)
http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=23714

Answer (score 1):

My understanding is that the XNA tools are free downloads, but that you have to have an App Hub membership if you want to sell XBox or Windows Phone games through the network.  See [here](http://create.msdn.com/en-US/home/getting_started) for more info.

Answer (score 1):

XNA is good but it might be better to stick to core technologies (DirectX) by using a dot net wrapper such as Managed DirectX (from Microsoft, deprecated but usable) or SlimDX ([SlimDX.org](http://slimdx.org/))

(Learning XNA might prove to be a waste of time and energy, as it is not a core MS product - it also changes drastically every time it is released and it hides much of DirectX so you don't have anything to put on your CV/resume)

Comment: Yeah, I get your point. Things like XNA come and go but if you know concrete stuff like Direct X it always helps. And anyway XNA IS basically a wrapper of Direct X.

Answer (score 0):

You can try XNA Framework. You can develop for PC, XBOX, and Windows Phone. If you're a student, you can get it from www.dreamspark.com for free.

Answer (score 0):

If you interested in C# game programming best choice (imho) is Unity (http://unity3d.com/). Because its free (not Pro), powerfull, level editor included , based on Mono etc